# Writing a specific JavaScript declaration more succinctly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A beginner question: how would you write the following code in a more succinct manner? I feel like I’m violating the `DRY` principle.

```
const goToPreviousSection = document.createElement("button")
const goToNextSection = document.createElement("button")

document.body.appendChild(goToPreviousSection)
document.body.appendChild(goToNextSection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original 4 lines are clearer and more elegant than all the answers posted so far.

I think they’re great answers only if you plan to have *more* buttons than your example. Otherwise don’t worry about DRY.

Answer (score 2):

The logical thing is to create a function.

```
function makeButton() {
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  return btn;
}

const goToPreviousSection = makeButton(), goToNextSection = makeButton();
```

Comment: The array literal and destructuring seem a little pointless here.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I was in two minds about making a function called `makeButtons`, and then destructure that way.  But then changed my mind to keep it simpler, but didn't change the destructure logic.   I should maybe update, and add that way too...  ps. cheers, I can get back to fortnight now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

> `ParentNode.append()` can append several nodes and strings, whereas `Node.appendChild()` can only append one node.

You can use `append()` insted of `appendChild()` to make it with single line:

```js
function createButton(txt){
  var b = document.createElement("button");
  b.textContent = txt;
  return b;
}
document.body.append(createButton('Prev'),createButton('Next'));
```

Comment: And what about the repetition of `createElement`? This for instance does not work: `let goToPreviousSection, goToNextSection;  goToPreviousSection = goToNextSection = document.createElement("button")`

Comment: Note that `ParentNode.append()` is not supported by IE.

Comment: @Mamun Thanks! `jo_va`’s answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to create elements

```js
function createElem(elemName, txt) {
  let elem = document.createElement(elemName);
  let content = document.createTextNode(txt);
  return elem.appendChild(content);
}

function appendToBody(elem) {
  document.body.appendChild(elem)
}

appendToBody(createElem('button', 'Previous'));
appendToBody(createElem('button', 'Next'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more functional way to do it, starting with a list of buttons, then doing the insert, using two functions makeButton and insertButton:

```js
const makeButton = () => document.createElement("button")
const insertButton = button => {
  document.body.append(button)
  return button
}

const [goToPreviousSection, goToNextSection] = [
  makeButton(),
  makeButton()
].map(insertButton)
```

Comment: But you didn't assign `goToPreviousSection` and `goToNextSection` constants, which are specifically needed later in the code. By the way, label is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. But as I wrote in the previous comment, `['Prev', 'Next']` is unnecessary. Could you leave it out?

Comment: Absolutely, I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an appendBtn function

```
function appendBtn(){
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
}
```

later use the return value to perform other operations like changing style,

```
let goToPreviousSection = appendBtn();
goToPreviousSection.style.background = "red";
```

hope this helps.